# Converting IF statements for use in SUMIF/COUNTIF [or conditional formatting] Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I've been trying to get to grips with SUMIF & COUNTIF functions in Excel recently, with limited success. I've realised the crux of the problem is that help pages give far too specific examples, including the official Office support.

I already know how to put together complex tests with multiple criteria already, using IF statements. What I really need is a guide to how to convert IF statements for use in such functions.

The real issue for me is what happens to cell references? I have a column of cells, each with some value for a given property. With an IF function I can go into the adjacent column, test the neighbouring cell using some criterion or set of criteria to find its value for a given property, and return an appropriate answer. I click and drag my formula down to check all the cells.

Eg. `A1:A10` are the cells I'm testing. The **property** I'm checking is their length, whose **value** will be the number of characters. The **appropriate answer** will be whether the number of characters is above or below a threshold.

Put together; `IF(LEN(A1)>50,"above","below")`

Pasted into `B1` and dragged down to `B10` I get an array of answers.

Suppose I want to count all the cells which meet the condition, that's where I'm stumped. COUNTIF looks like I could just specify the range (`A1:A10`) and condition `LEN(A1)>50` and get my answers. But what do I put inside `LEN()`? I want to go through and check for each cell in the range, how can I specify just one? Specifying none: `LEN()` or the range `LEN(A1:A10)` won't work.

For highlighting cells (conditional formatting), it's easy, just put the top left cell of the array, `so LEN(A1)`, but that doesn't work either!

I hope that's made the problem clear. Obviously I could just have 
`IF(LEN(A1)>50,1,0)` in `B1:B10`, and `SUM(B1:B10)` in C1 or something, thus counting all the cells which match the criteria in the if statement. But that seems like a totally retrograde step which negates the benefits of COUNTIF entirely. *Namely that it saves space and reduces complexity in the sheet by doing away with intermediate steps.*

And I have at least 1 sheet for which that definitely won't work owing to the volatile nature of my array sizes; I wouldn't be able to fit the additional intermediate columns if I wanted to!

SO, can *any* IF-statement-style check be converted to work with COUNTIF/SUMIF, if so then how, and are there any other tips you could include in case someone with a similar problem comes searching? Thanks so much for answers and help!

Comment: For conditional formatting, =len(A1)>50 extended to other cells as required should work OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(LEN(A1:A10)>50))
```

COUNTIF/SUMIF do not like it when you try to modify the range to be tested.  You can do a lot with the criteria, but not the range.  It is what is given up to use it in a non array form.